# SQL query to calculate a running tally taking initial inputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below. Each city will have a row where `TYPE` = `Active` and `Month` = `0` then there will be an `X` number of `Push` rows, starting with `Month` = `0` going to `Month` = `X`. In the example below `X` = `3`.

I need to create a query that generates the second table.

Basically, for each city:

- take the `Active` and `Push` value for `Month` = `0` and add them to get the `Final` value for `Month` = `0`
- then for each `Month`, take the previous month's `Final` value and add it to the months `Push` value from the first table.

I think I have to use `SUM` and `OVER` or `ROLLUP` but I am not sure how or where to start.

SQL Fiddle does not seem to be working so I have included the CREATE/INSERT statements to initialize the first table.

Edit: I found `db<>fiddle` - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9dab5f207b97a318c7d0f26369a4b3ed.

## First Table

```
+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| CITY  |  TYPE  | MONTH | VALUE |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| one   | Active | 0     | 222   |
| one   | Push   | 0     | -7    |
| one   | Push   | 1     | 1     |
| one   | Push   | 2     | -6    |
| one   | Push   | 3     | 0     |
| two   | Active | 0     | 363   |
| two   | Push   | 0     | -5    |
| two   | Push   | 1     | 4     |
| two   | Push   | 2     | -5    |
| two   | Push   | 3     | 5     |
| three | Active | 0     | 394   |
| three | Push   | 0     | 10    |
| three | Push   | 1     | 5     |
| three | Push   | 2     | -8    |
| three | Push   | 3     | 0     |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

## Expected Output

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| CITY  | TYPE  | MONTH | VALUE |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| one   | Final | 0     | 215   | 222 + -7 (add the active and next rows for month 0 for city one from the first table)
| one   | Final | 1     | 216   | 215 + 1 (previous month's final from this table plus this months push from the other table)
| one   | Final | 2     | 210   | 216 + -6 (previous month's final from this table plus this months push from the other table)
| one   | Final | 3     | 210   | ...etc
| two   | Final | 0     | 358   | 363 + -5 (add the active and next rows for month 0 for city two from the first table)
| two   | Final | 1     | 362   | ...etc
| two   | Final | 2     | 357   | ...etc
| two   | Final | 3     | 362   | ...etc
| three | Final | 0     | 404   | ...etc
| three | Final | 1     | 409   | ...etc
| three | Final | 2     | 401   | ...etc
| three | Final | 3     | 401   | ...etc
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

## Init SQL

```
CREATE TABLE cities
(
    [city] varchar(10)
  , [type] varchar(10)
  , [month] int
  , [value] int
);

INSERT INTO cities ([city], [type], [month], [value])
VALUES
    ('one','Active',0,222),
    ('one','Push',0,-7),
    ('one','Push',1,1),
    ('one','Push',2,-6),
    ('one','Push',3,0),
    ('two','Active',0,363),
    ('two','Push',0,-5),
    ('two','Push',1,4),
    ('two','Push',2,-5),
    ('two','Push',3,5),
    ('three','Active',0,394),
    ('three','Push',0,10),
    ('three','Push',1,5),
    ('three','Push',2,-8),
    ('three','Push',3,0)
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
select distinct city, 'final' as [type], [month], 
       sum(value) over (partition by city order by [month]) AS Value
from table t;
```

As your sample data suggests you need order by with `month` only.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT city ,
       'Final' AS Type ,
       t.month ,
       t.Value
FROM   (   SELECT city ,
                  [type] ,
                  [month] ,
                  SUM(value) OVER ( PARTITION BY city
                                    ORDER BY type ,
                                             month ) AS Value
           FROM   #cities ) t
WHERE  t.type = 'Push';
```

Result:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| city  | Type  | month | Value |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| one   | Final |     0 |   215 |
| one   | Final |     1 |   216 |
| one   | Final |     2 |   210 |
| one   | Final |     3 |   210 |
| three | Final |     0 |   404 |
| three | Final |     1 |   409 |
| three | Final |     2 |   401 |
| three | Final |     3 |   401 |
| two   | Final |     0 |   358 |
| two   | Final |     1 |   362 |
| two   | Final |     2 |   357 |
| two   | Final |     3 |   362 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using aggregation and a cumulative sum:

```
select city, 'final' as [type], [month], 
       sum(sum(value)) over (partition by city order by [month]) AS Value
from table t
group by city, month
order by city, month;
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test this query, but hopefully it will help you.

```
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE AS
SELECT a.CITY, 'Final', a.MONTH, 
       SUM(
            (
              SELECT x.VALUE
              FROM TABLE1 x
              WHERE x.MONTH <= a.MONTH
              AND x.CITY = a.CITY
            )
          ) AS VALUE

FROM TABLE1 a
WHERE a.TYPE = 'PUSH'
GROUP BY a.CITY, a.MONTH
```

Comment: I am getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.`. And if I don't include the `CREATE TABLE` then I get `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan didn't you get the logic here?

Comment: Yes. I understand. Thank you!